# Java 8 Streams - Throwing an exception in the middle of an iteration

Tags: exception, java-8, java-stream

I have the following array

```
ArrayList<Car> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to iterate it and throw an exception if it contains a certain value

i.e.

if at least one

```
list.stream.filter(x -> x.color.equals("Black"));
```

then I want to stop iteration and throw an exception.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest is:

```
list.forEach( x -> {
    if(x.color.equals("Black")) throw new RuntimeException();
});
```

Comment: If you're using this approach, then there's no need to call `stream()`. `list.forEach` is sufficient.

Comment: You're of course right, I was blinded by the OP's code example

Comment: What is the difference between stream.foreach and foreach?

Comment: @rails: [`Iterable.forEach`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) does not create a `Stream` but is also limited to iterating, i.e. can’t be combined with [`map` nor `filter`, etc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description)

Answer (score 9):

You could use `anyMatch` for this:

```
boolean matched = list.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.color.equals("Black"));
if(matched) throw new SomeException();
```

Since it does not evaluate the rest of the pipeline if the condition is satisfied for one element when iterating through it, and that it returns false if the stream is empty, I think this is what you are looking for.

Of course, you could do it in a single statement but it may not improve readability depending on the situation:

```
if(list.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.color.equals("Black"))) {
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

Comment: Unlike the `forEach` approach, this will allow you to throw a checked exception.